# ERROR Error: invalid Server Side Rendering

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular9

I am using this commands to build and run my project in SSR mode.

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

The build finish with success and the server start up correctly but in the first request to http://localhost:4000/ I got this error:

```
ERROR Error: invalid
at ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4792305)
at NodeInjectorFactory.ToastyComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:///ToastyComponent/ɵfac.js:3:43)
at getNodeInjectable (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4819897)
at instantiateAllDirectives (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4857508)
at createDirectivesInstances (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4857745)
at ɵɵelementStart (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4942423)
at Module.ɵɵelement (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4943502)
at AppComponent_Template (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:3105548)
at executeTemplate (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4856642)
at renderView (/Users/david/Documents/tracegaming/web/dist/web/server/main.js:1:4852371)
```

this return internal server error.

Here is my *server.ts* file

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import 'localstorage-polyfill'

global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/web/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: The ng information is irrelevant, remove it from your post. Instead, show your server's code, because it's crashing on a simple request to `/`, so what is the code that kicks in for that route? (not "is supposed to kick in", but what code _actually_ kicks in?)

Comment: Don't use `server.get('*.*', ...)` for static content, use [server.use](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). That said, the error is about renderView, so: what's in `indexHtml` just before you call `res.render`, and what's in that options object you're passing along, too? And equally importantly: why on earth are you packing the entire `req` object into the render context? That should _not_ ever be necessary O_o

Comment: The `indexHtml` has a `index`. I just run `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` to create `server.ts`, the req object is added automatically on the render. I removed req object and i got this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined` at View.engine